# MySQL check if value is in result set before summing

Tags: mysql

I have a table of ratings for comments, when I fetch comments, I also fetch the ratings and I also want to be able to display which comments the logged user has already voted on. This is what I am doing now

```
SELECT 
c.id, 
c.text, 
c.datetime, 
c.author, 
u.email AS author_name, 
SUM(cr.vote) AS rating, 
cr2.vote AS voted

FROM comments c 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = c.author 
LEFT JOIN comments_ratings cr ON c.id = cr.comment 
LEFT JOIN comments_ratings cr2 ON c.id = cr2.comment AND cr2.user = :logged_user_id 

GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

But I don't like how I'm performing a second join on the same table. I know it is perfectly valid but if I could get the information I want from the first join, which is there anyway, why perform a second one?

Is it possible to figure out if a row with column `user` equal to `:logged_user_id` exists on table `comments_ratings cr` before executing the aggregate function(s)?

P.S.: If someone could come up with a better title, people can find in future, I'd also appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.id, c.text, c.datetime, c.author, u.email AS author_name, 
       SUM(cr.vote) AS rating, 
       MAX(cr.user = :logged_user_id) as voted
FROM comments c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = c.author LEFT JOIN
     comments_ratings cr
     ON c.id = cr.comment 
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.id DESC;
```

Comment: Although the code works, I'm having a hard time figuring out how it works. If it's supposed to get the maximum value of all records matching the condition `cr.user = logged_id` then isn't it supposed to be equal to the id itself? What am I missing?

Comment: The expression `cr.user = :logged_user_id` is a boolean expression.  In a numeric context, this takes on the value of 1 if true and 0 if false.  The `max()` will return 1 if the expression is ever true -- that is, if there is ever a match.

Comment: So if I wanted to get the vote's value instead of just 1 or 0 would you say that something like this is okay and is not going to be slowing down the query a lot -- `MAX(IF(cr.user = :logged_user_id, cr.vote, NULL)) AS voted`?

Comment: @php_nub_qq . . . I would use `case`, but yes, that is the correct logic.

Comment: Why? Logically `IF` is the correct statement to use because there are not many possible outcomes, it is either true or false, or I am wrong yet again?

Comment: @php_nub_qq . . . `case` is the ANSI standard method of creating conditional expressions.  `if()` is an extension specific to MySQL.